# How many exterior stencil lettering (marking out maintenance or critical flight parts) are there on a Delta 767-300?

Tags: aircraft-identification

I was wondering how many different stenciling areas are located on a Delta 767-300 and wanted to know general locations of each. Some examples include the markings of "Static Port" and the APU exhuast. If there is stencil markings of with 5 lines of text, photos would greatly be appreciated.